# Purple for visited hyperlinks unless buttons

Tags: css, anchor

The design is for hyperlinks to be in purple if they have been visitied before. However buttons are also hyperlinks and their colors should not be changed.

The following `css` code is not working properly:

```css
a:visited:not(.button),
a:visited:not(.tcm-btn) {
// a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

//a.button:visited {
//   color: #fff;
//}

//a.tcm-btn:visited {
//   color: #fff;
//}
```

If the comments (denoted by `//`) are removed and, comments are applied to the first two lines instead, everything works fine.

However, the method that works is not desirable. Although the buttons may be white today, they may not be tomorrow.

Can the desirable design be implemented by changing syntax somehow?

---

### Edit - Add HTML

As per request, HTML is below:

```html
      <a href="/index.html" style="display: inline" class="button">⌂ Home</a>
      <a href="/about.html" style="display: inline" class="button">❓ About</a>
      <a href="/answers.html" style="display: inline" class="button">✅ Answers</a>
      <a href="/programs.html" style="display: inline" class="button"> Programs</a>

      <!-- The Cookie Machine - Hidden Button -->
      <a href="#0" class="tcm-btn">tCM</a>
```

Comment: Please show the html code of them to make sure for more info?

Comment: @TinySonhh HTML added

Comment: `//` is not for comments in CSS, only `/* */`-style comments work in CSS.

Comment: @Dai Technically it scss / Sass

Comment: Because `:visited` is _by default_ `purple`, your `:not` selector isn't really overriding anything. Rather, you can override the button links by `a.button:visited { color: inherit; }`.

Comment: @BumhanYu Could you post an answer so I can test and accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `:visited` is *by default* purple, your `:not` selector isn't really overriding anything. In this case, you can override the button links by

```css
a.button:visited { 
  color: inherit; 
}
```

A working example below. Try Command (CTRL) clicking the link to see how it renders visited hyperlinks.

```css
a:visited {
  color: red;
}

a.button:visited {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">Default `A` tag</a>
<a class="button" href="https://google.com">`A` tag with `button` class</a>
```

###### Updated: why and how

1. By default, `:visited` links render with purple underlined style.
2. Optionally `:visited` links can styled along a few limited properties (see [MDN page for ':visited'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited))
3. Setting `color: inherit;` will override whatever the color value it's given, and force-inherit its parent's style. (see [MDN page for 'inherit'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit))

   - In this case, `a.button:visited` will override its default `purple` color and inherit its parent's color (i.e. `body`'s `color`) instead.

Comment: Although I can't explain how this works, I can confirm it does work. Accepted.

Comment: Added a few bullets to outline the whys and hows.